# How can I print multiple .csv files side by side in bash and find the difference between the 3

Tags: bash, scripting

I have 3 .csv files how to get the difference between them 
For Example :

INPUT :

```
SYMBOL QTY      |     SYMBOL  QTY    | SYMBOL QTY 
A   -   100               A   -    100      A    -  90
B    -  100            B     -   50      B   -   100
```

OUTPUT:

```
A 90
B 50
```

TRIED :

```
join -t"," -1 1 -2 1 -a1 file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, ' BEGIN {
        print "ID,field,old,new"
} NF > 3 {
        if ( $3 != $5 )
                print $1, "cost", $3, $5
        if ( $2 != $4 )
                print $1, "version", $2, $4
} ' OFS=,
```

Comment: Please EDIT your question more carefully, as we can't see separate Input and output. 2nd important point, please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your post. Also do a search too on Stack overflow itself you may find help here too.

Comment: No, not clear still. Please go through few posts in Stack overflow and see how people ask question. You can check once that link which I had given for example once.

Comment: This is an XY problem.

Comment: @NidhiShah, please see this link once https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can use paste.

```
paste  "yourFolderPath"/output1.csv "yourFolderPath"/output2.csv "yourFolderPath"/output3.csv > "yourFolderPath"/mergedFile.csv
```

Just have in mind that the default delimiter for paste is the tab character. You can change that with -d to use commas.

```
paste -d ','
```